# Ayuda al imprimir valores binarios de un algoritmo de huffman

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

estoy realizando un árbol de Huffman y quiero mostrar en pantalla el resultado del mensaje. Algo como:

```
Mensaje Original: Hola mundo
Huffman: 10010100010101010101
```

Pero tengo problemas al guardar los números para imprimirlos en orden del mensaje.

```
/*
 *  Lo ideal sería que fuera vector<char*> Numero
 *  para que guardara las cosas algo así:
 *  Numero[] = { "1001", "001", "1111"....}
 *  enconces al mandar imprimir a Numero[0] saldría
 *  1001 en pantalla.
*/
vector<char> Letras;
vector<int> Numero;
cout << "Peso binario de cada letra" << endl;
for(CodigoHuffmanMap::const_iterator it = Bin.begin(); it != Bin.end(); ++it){
    // Imprimir y guardar la letra.     
    cout << it->first << " = ";
    Letras.push_back(it->first);
    // Imprimir el número. E.g. 1001
    copy(it->second.begin(), it->second.end(), ostream_iterator<bool>(cout));
    cout << endl;       
    // Guardar la cadena de números "1010" en vector<char*> Numero  
    copy(it->second.begin(), it->second.end(), back_inserter(Numero));  
}

cout << "Comprension" << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(EnunciadoPrueba); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < Letras.size(); j++){
        if(Letras[j] == EnunciadoPrueba[i]){
            // Comprueba que está en orden imprimiendo Letras[j]
            // en lugar de Numero[j]
            cout << Numero[j];
            continue;
        }
    }
}   
cout << endl << "Todos los numeros que deberian salir en pantalla." << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < Numero.size(); i++)
    cout << Numero[i];
```

El problema es que cuando guardo los números sólo puedo hacerlo con vector < int >Numero y eso me genera las salidas:

```
cout << Numero[0]; // 1
```

Cuando lo que quisiera es guardarlo en una string o char, para que:

```
cout << Numero[0];  // 10001
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para próximas preguntas recuerda que es importante indicar detalles como el tipo de todas las variables. Sirva el ejemplo de `CodigoHuffmanMap::const_iterator`. Si no llegas a usar `ostream_iterator<bool>(cout)` no habría tenido forma de adivinarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema, como comentas, es que estás trabajando con secuencias en vez de con números. Los dígitos a la izquierda son significativos y eso un tipo entero no lo soporta. De ahí que no puedas agrupar cada secuencia en un único índice del vector `Numero`.

Una solución pasa por sustituir `Numero` para que pase a almacenar elementso de tipo `string`:

```
std::vector<std::string> Numero;
```

Ahora, para cada letra, convertimos la secuencia booleana en una cadena:

```
for(CodigoHuffmanMap::const_iterator it = Bin.begin(); it != Bin.end(); ++it){
    // ...
    std::string secuencia;
    for( bool val : it->second)
      secuencia.append(std::to_string(val));

    Numero.push_back(secuencia);
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Esto lo solucionó perfecto.